# from gerrit submit a change to gitlab failed

Tags: gitlab, gerrit, cicd, git-lfs

Im using gerrit with gerrit-lfs plugin submit a change to gitlab failed.

I've tried submit a simple file whithout lfs, it can normally merged to gitlab. and then I tried to
submit a bigfile. it can successfully push to gerrit,but cant merge to gitlab
error msg like:

```
Failed replicate of refs/changes/xxxx to  gitserverxxx, reason:pre-recive hook declined
```

about 10 minutes later， I retry to submit a simple file, it failed yet, and I got same error as before.

what should I do? and how to debug it?